# How to enable monospaced Test Explorer output?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, output, consolas

Is there a way to enable monospaced fonts like `Consolas` for output of `Test Explorer` in Visual Studio other than aligning entire UI through `Environment` setting?

Just want to print a fine looking table in output but always get aligned garbage. Setting `Environment` just make VS look too bulky.

**Current workaround:**

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Show settings for: -> Environment

Answer (score 0):

What version of Visual Studio are you running? In VS2019 I see test output printed in a monospace font.

```cs
public class UnitTest1
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;

    public UnitTest1(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        _output.WriteLine("A B C D E F G");
        _output.WriteLine("1 2 3 4 5 6 7");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: VS 2019 and I have "Open additional output for this result" link instead of your case.

Comment: What exact VS version (e.g. 16.11), and what test framework are you using? My example uses xUnit.